# Regex to find session state tag in web.config

Tags: c#, html, regex, web-config, session-state

I may have a simple sesion state tag with self enclosing tag

1. sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=CTSINTCOVOCPRD4:42424" />
2. sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=CTSINTCOVOCPRD4:42424" /sessionState>

sessionState closing tag may be in the same line or next line. sessionState tag may also have any other setting tags inside it.

I need to find all this scenarios to get full sessionState tag and delete it from config file.

I wrote following lines of code:

```
                if (Content.Contains("sessionState"))
                {
                    string RegularExpressionPattern = @"<sessionState.*?><\/sessionState>|<sessionState.*?>|<sessionState.*?>\n<\/sessionState>";
                    Regex myRegex = new Regex(RegularExpressionPattern, RegexOptions.None);
                    MatchCollection collection = myRegex.Matches(Content);
                    string stripped = collection[0].Value;
                    Content = Content.Replace(stripped, "");
                    return Content;
                }
```

Content: config file content

I am getting sessionState tag with self enclosing tag and sessionState with closing tag in the same line, but not getting proper value, if sessionState closing tag is in the next line or if it has any another setting tag inside sessionState tag.

Where am I doing wrong in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use :

```
var sessionStatString = (SessionStateSection)WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/sessionState");
```

For SessionStateSection : import namespace, `using System.Web.Configuration;`

**UPDATE:**

```
Regex.Replace(Content, "</?(sessionState|SESSIONSTATE).*?>", string.Empty)
```

**Note:** I strongly recommend not to update configuration file run time

Comment: I am getting "{System.Web.Configuration.SessionStateSection}" value and not the sessionStatetag?

Comment: Yes, so from sessionStatString you will get the value which you want. Like : **sessionStatString.Mode**, **sessionStatString.stateConnectionString**

Comment: Why do you want to update your web.config run time ? its not a good practice

Comment: I do not want value like mode or stateconnectionstring, but want full sessionState tag.
Like <sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=CTSINTCOVOCPRD4:42424" />

Comment: I want to delete and sessionState tag will then get referred from root config, just to avoid repeatation. So, please let m,e know if I can get full session tag, whatever it may have inside.

Comment: have a look at my updated answer. Don't forget to upvote and mark it as an answer if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the update. If I have sessionState closing tag in next line, How can I get the value then?
I am getting 2 counts in collection object, which I have used in my code. So, I am appending both count values to get the value in stripped variable, but it wont work , if closing tag is in next line or if it has another setting inside the sessionState tag.
Am I clear?

Comment: You want to make whole string of **SesstionState** empty right ? For that just use **Regex.Replace**. It will replace your whole string whether it is in next line or not.